# Grunt serve:www working but not being recognized by c9

Tags: gruntjs, cloud9-ide, yeoman-generator-angular

I `grunt build` and `grunt serve:www` just fine, but when I go to the url where it should be hosted, it says there is no application currently running. Grunt config is:

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port:process.env.PORT,
    hostname: process.env.IP//,
    //livereload: 35729
  },
```

Any ideas why this might be?
App uses Yeoman, angular, bower, and grunt